# Should multiple data contract be created for same entity

Tags: c#, wcf

By the design is it a good idea to create multiple data contracts for a same entity?

For example I have a table called [Person], at the beginning there are only two field: ID and Name. I use nHibernate to map the entity and mark it as data contract to expose the original entity to the client.

With further development more and more column are added to the table: height, sex, address... blah blah blah

When client tries to retrieve a Person object, a large object with a lots of useless property are also delivered.

Is it a good design that, I create another class [PersonWithNameOnly] or such as [PersonLite] for some methods that provides a lite object of that dto? I'm worried that it will create a lot of data contract.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, it is a good practice to expose a ViewModel containing only what is required by the client. 
The principle is to work only with the data the current layer need to work with, such as [micro services architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices).

However, because developing a new ViewModel for each endpoint can be time consuming, you will see some projects on which a ViewModel can be used for several endpoints, containing a lot of properties. But obviously, that is not the best practice.

That is why people try to provide solutions to this problem, such as [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/), which is able to provide only the fields the client have required to get.

Hope it is a bit clearer.